# How can I add multiple images to ViewPager from URL in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I am looking to display multiple images that I currently have on my website on a ViewPager that I have on an app that I am making. I have tried different methods but just can't get it to work. Here is my code:

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    private static final int COUNT = 1;

    ImageAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

        new LoadImage(imageView).execute("http://ingridwu.dmmdmcfatter.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/placeholder.png");
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);

        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }

    private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
        ImageView img = null;

        public LoadImage(ImageView img) {
            this.img = img;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(args[0].getContent());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {
            if (image != null) {
                img.setImageBitmap(image);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#333" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="360dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So like I said, I want to be able to add multiple images from URLs. I even tried setting COUNT = 2 and creating a new LoadImage and adding it to view just like I add the first image but it sets the first link to both images, then, when I swipe, it changes both images to link #2 and that is how it stays. Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you need to create an array of image urls's and here (.execute("http://ingridwu.dmmdmcfatter.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/placeholder.png");) you change to (.execute(array_of_urls[position]));) have a look here --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591154/android-viewpager-downloading-the-images-from-url

Comment: @Tasos this works great! Thank you so much! If you would like, write your comment as an answer so I can vote it as best answer! Thank you again!